# Creating a data frame in R which is an interaction of a row and subsequent rows of another data frame

Tags: r

This isn't the exact problem but its the general idea

```
test<-data.frame(rbind(c(1,2,3), c(4, 5, 6), c(7, 8, 9), c(1, 2, 3))) 
names(test)[1] <- "one"
names(test)[2] <- "two"
names(test)[3] <- "three"
```

So I basically want to create a new data frame containing one column where each row is row(I)- row(I+1) of the test data frame

such as:

```
test[1,1]-test[2,1]
test[2,1]-test[3,1]
test[3,1]-test[4,1]...
```

I;ve tried:

```
k<-nrow(test)
for(i in 1:k-1){
  test2<-data.frame(test[i,1]-test[i+1,1])
}
```

but this is just producing one value

also then to add a final row '0', so there are k rows in total

Comment: Please post expected result

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `diff(test$one)`

Comment: or rather `data.frame(new_one = c(-diff(test$one), 0))`

Comment: Yes that's it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For your row to row substraction, you need to loop through your rows and columns:

```
k<-nrow(test)
n <- ncol(test)
for (j in 1:n){

  for(i in 1:k-1){

    test[i,n + j] <- test[i,j]-test[i+1,j]
    i = i+1
  }
}
```

To add a new row:

```
test[k+1,] <- matrix(0,nrow=1, ncol=n)
```